# Avoiding false positives with clang's ThreadSanitizer and TBB

Tags: c++, clang, race-condition, tbb, thread-sanitizer

Has anyone tried [clang's ThreadSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) with [Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks)?

My experience so far was that you will get a lot of warnings, even for relatively simple examples. Unfortunately, many of them seem to be false positives.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150069/783510) to another ThreadSanitizer question, suppression files are recommended. Could that help? Is there a suppression file for TBB or any other technique?

(Side note: With [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), it looks similar. Many false positives.)

Comment: Don't use atomics of any kind, as soon as you do, none of these tools seem to work well at all.

Comment: I just posted another related question (libstdc++ atomics instead of tbb), if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128549/force-use-of-locks-inside-stdatomic-during-debugging-with-libstdc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I only got it working when I reference the suppression file in `TSAN_OPTIONS`. At least for me, only referencing in during compilation with `-fsanitize-blacklist` did not work with the environment variable.

Anyway, here is a possible suppression file

```
# sanitizer-thread-suppressions.txt
race:^tbb*
```

... and that is how you can use it:

```
TSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=sanitizer-thread-suppressions.txt" ./my_binary
```

If you increase verbosity, you should see outputs like these:

```
TSAN_OPTIONS="verbosity=2 suppressions=sanitizer-thread-suppressions.txt" ./my_binary
...
ThreadSanitizer: matched suppression '^tbb*'
```

Please note that the pattern `^tbb*` is simple but potentially dangerous as it might hide warnings in your own code. More realistic would be something like this:

```
race:^__interceptor_memset*
race:^tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode*
race:^tbb::blocked_range*
race:^tbb::interface9::internal::start_for*
race:^tbb::internal::machine_load_store*
race:^tbb::strict_ppl::internal::micro_queue*
```