# Force use of locks inside std::atomic during debugging with libstdc++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, libstdc++

I've done a bit of a google and can't seem to turn up a **GCC** option or **libstdc++** macro for this. Is it possible to force the use of locking internally on all the `std::atomic` template specializations. On some platforms some of the specializations are locking anyway, so it certainly seems like a feasible option.

In the past I've found the use of `std::atomic` to be very painful when debugging data-races with tools such as **Valgrind** (**Helgrind** or **DRD**) due to the enormous number of false positives. If use of atomics is pervasive enough, suppression files seem to not be a very scalable solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can try tools like ThreadSanitizer instead. There are couple implementations: https://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer and http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html

Comment: I was under the impression ThreadSanitizer wasn't able to distinguish between atomics and race-conditions either?

Comment: I'm not certain about the Valgrind version but tsan in llvm handles atomics by replacing atomic instructions in the IR with calls to tsan functions. See slide 25 [here](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Serebryany_TSan-MSan.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way, AFAIK. GCC implements C++11 atomics via lock-free builtin functions (`__atomic_fetch_add`, `__atomic_test_and_set`, etc). Depending on what is available in the machine definition, GCC may emit some efficient insn sequence or, as a last resort, use a compare-and-swap loop. If nothing useful is available, GCC just emits calls to external functions with the same names and arguments.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins

PS. Actually, you may compile with `-m32 -march=i386` and provide yourself the required external functions.